# Should the constant value be included in computing for factorials?

Tags: factorial

In our math class today, we had a disagreement regarding factorials in this question:

> Six students in a speech class will have to give their speech on the
>   same day. One of the students insists on being first. If this student's
>   request is granted, how many different ways are there to schedule the
>   speeches?

Some students stated that the answer should be $5!$ while the provided answer key says it should be $6!$

Answer (score 2):

$5!$, we no longer have any more decision to make for the first student anymore.

To make it even clearer, suppose there are only $2$ students and one student insists to be the first. If the wish is granted, then there is only $1!$ possibility.